# Is there a clean way to style individual Wordpress nav menu elements?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navigation, nav

The navigation menu in the Wordpress theme that I'm coding has two different colours of text within the same nav item.

```
<span class="nav-item-first">About</span><br /><span class="nav-item-second">Us</span>
```

I know that I can add a span class in the WP menu options. If there's a way that I can keep this tidy so that when I hand it over to the client all they see is "About Us" instead of all the code in the WP menu options, that'd be ideal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You can re-code it this way, as the whole thing would be inside some `<a>` tag right?

```
<a href="#">About <span>Us</span></a>
```

#### And give the CSS this way:

```
a {color: #f00;}
a span {display: block; color: #00f;}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is a stylistic element, I think it would be safe to use javascript to replace the original content, so the HTML can remain clean, and you have a script to replace it with your complex HTML.

It is worth noting that javascript can not be relied on 100% for this task due to various circumstances where it is not rendered, not least of which, when the page is printed.